# Building an ElasticSearch Multi-Filter Aggregate errors out

Tags: elasticsearch

Here is my ES payload:

```
{
  "filtered": {
    "filter": {
      "and": {
        "filters": [
          {
            "status": [
              "error",
              "active",
              "opt_out"
            ]
          },
          {
            "group_ids": [
              "UUIDs-go-here"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "status_count": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "status"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The error I am receiving is `Parse Failure [No parser for element [filtered]]];`

I was following this https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-and-filter.html to help build out my filters, but obviously I am doing something wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "filter": {
            "and": {
               "filters": [
                  {
                      "terms": {
                         "status": [
                            "error",
                            "active",
                            "opt_out"
                         ]
                      }
                  },
                  {
                      "terms": {
                         "group_ids": [
                            "UUIDs-go-here"
                         ]
                      }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "aggs": {
      "status_count": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "status"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Wrap your entire `filtered query` in the query syntax, as `filtered` is a type of query and not a query itself. Then, in your `and filters`, you also need to specify what kind of and filters you are running, as `status` is not a type of filter. I assumed here that your were looking for `terms` filters on the fields.